# An error occurred while writing to logger(s) from System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am getting a random exception for a web API hosted in an App Service in Azure. I don't see this is a problem related to my code. Here is the error message and stack trace from Application Insights:

```
Message An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another pr…[show more]    
Exception type  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception    
Failed method   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent
```

With the following stack trace:

```
System.AggregateException:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage+<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2.<Define>b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcCoreLoggerExtensions.ActionMethodExecuting (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1+<ProcessRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception handled at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log:
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent (System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent (System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog.WriteEntry (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.WriteMessage (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                logging.AddEventLog();
            });
}
```

and appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help with the idea when it happens or might happen would be beneficial.

Comment: Did you try restarting the App Service? Do you see this happening consistently even then?

Comment: Did you finally figured the cause ?

Comment: nope, I still see those errors in app insight

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT I tried restarting the app service, didn't help.

Comment: @SharifMamun Do they stop the execution of your code ?

Comment: nope, they don't

Comment: @foo-baar but it would be great if you find any clue on this!

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT I have been seeing this across many of my app services.  My analysis suggests that it happens when there is a large burst of logging attempts (such as when a dependency like a SQL database is failing, causing lots of requests to throw exceptions).  Some of the error logging calls end up hitting this exception, which in turn generates even more logging that further exacerbates the issue.  Lately I've started removing the EventLog logging provider from my app configurations in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: I started to get those exceptions - Didn't find solution for this but if you are using application insight like I do I created an interface ILogger and registered it to Logger class which I inject TelemetryClient and log it directly to application insight

Answer (score 1):

I have an application that was experiencing the same issues writing to the EventLogger in our .NET Core 3.1.0 Web API application running in Azure. We are using the built in ILogger<> along with NLog to persist logs to Stackify and Raygun.

Our application used the MediatR library and we wrapped our pipeline execution with additional logging such that every time a different command executed, we'd log how long it took. Our application used logging extensively. Most of these issues occurred when we had a significant increase in user activity.

These errors would show up in our logging in the form of an AggregateException:

`An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)`

With an Inner Exception:

`System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Byte[] data, Object[] values):170
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category):129
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.WriteMessage(String message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType, Int32 eventId):158
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func3 formatter)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func3 formatter, List1& exceptions, TState& state):45`

We'd essentially see hundreds of these errors and it would cause our application to become unresponsive and timeout requests. But--our application does not need EventSource logging, so we took the recommendation of @Dan Kroymann and removed the EventLog from the logging providers configured in Progam.cs, e.g.,

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseNLog());
```

You may need to reference additional nuget packages in order to use some of the logging extension methods:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug`

Once we put the above fix in place, we stopped seeing EventSource logging issues.

Comment: What if we do need Event Logs?

Comment: @Dagrooms then I might suggest creating a single static ApplicationLogger, registering that in Startup, and using that throughout the application. You would need to ensure that the resource, in this case, the EventLog, is not accessed concurrently.

Answer (score -2):

I was dealing with telegram bots when this error popped up, and after several attempts to finally solve it I found that the bot username was incorrect!